# Having trouble identifying value of inductor, what is its inductance?

Tags: inductor, markings

[image: photo of axial inductor]

Need help identifying this inductor's value. Unsure if it's 10 uH or 80 uH, it could be either depending on which way you read the bands.

Answer (score 8):

From the photo it looks like 10uH +/-10%.

The band color appears to be silver (not grey/gray), plus 80uH would not be an E12 value (8.2uH would be) and brown is a rather unlikely tolerance (1%) for this kind of inductor.

Comment: And usually the thicker band is the first one.